# how to solve Invalid Date {} JavaScript

Tags: javascript

when I try to get the year, the month and the time of a date, I get ***Invalid Date {}***

```js
const d = new Date();
let time = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getTime());
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = time;
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Comment: try let time = new Date(d.getTime())

Comment: Why do you use the second `new Date()` whats the desired output?

Comment: The `d.getTime()` should be `d.getDate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date().getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since midnight on Jan 1, 1970, while `new Date().getDay()`, which is what you're looking for, returns the current day.

```js
const d = new Date();
let time = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay());
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = time;
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for the number of milliseconds of a specific date on form year, month, time

Comment: I don't understand why getTime does glitch it

Comment: @bawinabawina Because the 3rd argument to the Date constructor is expected to be the day-of-month value but you're passing in the number of milliseconds that has passed since 1970-01-01, which is an extremely big number and completely nonsensical to use in place of the day-of-month value.

Comment: @Lennholm ok so I need to follow the form of this constructor ***new Date(year, monthIndex, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)*** !

Comment: @shreyasm-dev `getDay()` returns the current day-of-week value, i.e. a value between `0` and `6`. The correct method to use is `getDate()`, which returns the day-of-month value.

Comment: I accept your answer (thanks to comments under it I got a solution)

Answer (score 0):

well here are pair of errors in your code working with the javascript Date object API. d.getFullYear() gives 2022 and this is correct, and d.getMonth() returns the months starting by 0 but as you are showing the object directly you don't need to worry about that, the problem surges when you call d.getTime() that returns:

> A number representing the milliseconds elapsed between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date.

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime#return_value)

So maybe what you are trying to do is this instead:

```
        const d = new Date();           
        let time = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getUTCDate());
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = time;
```

Comment: I don't need utc date I need to ge the date on that form: year, month, time

Comment: @bawinabawina The way you initialize a Date has nothing to do with the format of the Date. A Date doesn't even have a particular format, all formatting is handled by the various "to string" methods.

Comment: I'm talking about my needs

Comment: @bawinabawina you can print that without pasing those values to a Date object, for example: `let time = d.getFullYear() +'-'+ d.getMonth() +'-'+ d.getTime();
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = time;`

Answer (score 0):

the month argument range from 0 to 11 in javasript, to get the correct month
try (d.getMonth()+1).

```
const d = new Date();

//I don't need utc date I need to ge the date on that form: year, month, time

let time = d.getUTCFullYear() + "," +(d.getMonth()+1) + ","+d.getTime();

console.log("time",time);
```